# Getting the column header in ExtJS grid

Tags: extjs, header, grid

I'm trying to retrieve the column header for each record in my ExtJS grid.

Currently I get the values with:

```
cellclick: function(view, td, cellIndex, record, tr, rowIndex, e, eOpts) {
    for(i=0; i < columns.length-1; i++){
            currentRecordKey = columns[i].dataIndex;
            newRecord[currentRecordKey] = record.get(currentRecordKey);
            console.log(newRecord[currentRecordKey]);
            /** var = Code to retrive each records column header **/
```

So far nothing I've tried works, any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out:

`currentRecordKey` held this value all along